# How do I find an element from a web page and import it into a Google Sheets cell?

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm attempting to scrape from this web page here: https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/14Jydka1ufeZBXAHNmjK9SWedvWtufdaJRbEMgtF8Bifc6Dv7Gm

I'm trying to find out how to pull the number below "Rewards(24H)" and import it into a cell.

I've tried using ImportXML function but it gave me the "Imported content is empty" error.

After doing some research, I think the element is not server-side because I can't find it in the source code. So I opened up the Developer Tools for the page, clicked the Network Tab and refreshed the page.

I filtered the results to see only the XHR parts. Clicking the Headers tab will display a number of APIs in the Request URL section.

This is as far as I have gotten. I cannot find any reference to the Rewards(24H) number in any of the JSON code.

It'd be much appreciated if anyone can explain how I can find that number and import it into a Google Sheets cell, preferably self updating every hour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing to the network requests of the above URL data is coming from the api.helium.io so you can follow below code to get your desired data and FYI that website provides API already and has docs here : [API Documentation](https://docs.helium.com/api/blockchain/introduction/) so if you other data you can follow this also and according to my guess you were not able to find the data cause it was rounded off to the 2 decimals where as API gives result up to 5 to 6 so that could be the reason you were not able to find the data which was displayed in XHR requests.

Code:

```
import datetime
import requests
dt = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
querystring = {"min_time":"-60 day","max_time":dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),"bucket":"day"}
response=requests.get('https://api.helium.io/v1/accounts/14Jydka1ufeZBXAHNmjK9SWedvWtufdaJRbEMgtF8Bifc6Dv7Gm/hotspots').json()
for data in response["data"]:
    print(f"name:{data['name']}")
    internal_data =requests.get(f"https://api.helium.io/v1/hotspots/{data['address']}/rewards/sum",params=querystring).json()
    last24hour=internal_data["data"][0]["total"]
    last7days=0
    for i in range(0,7):
        last7days+=internal_data["data"][i]["total"]
    last30days = 0
    for i in range(0, 30):
        last30days += internal_data["data"][i]["total"]
    print(f"24H : {round(last24hour,2)}")
    print(f"7D : {round(last7days, 2)}")
    print(f"30D : {round(last30days, 2)}")
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks J B, I'll look into this now.  Also, what language is your code written in?

Comment: its written in python language and I forget you can even needed to add this data to your google sheets right you could use [gspread](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/) library to add data to sheets.